# Excel formula to insert multiple elements in a range into an sql column without coding?

Tags: mysql, excel, excel-formula

I have a languages mysql table with different languages. In excel I make this formula to select all the data I want to insert:

```
      ="insert into languages(en) values ('"&B1:B4&"');"
```

It selects the fields i need(blue range can bee seen), but the otucome of the formula is this:

```
      "insert into languages(en) values ('pear');"
```

It should look like:

```
      "insert into languages(en) values ('pear'), ('melon'), ('apple'), ('peach');"
```

What am I missing in the formula? Is there an easy, and quick solution to solve this, or I need to write some code? And what should the code be like?

I am a beginner, please don't hate me :)

Comment: `TEXTJOIN()` might be what you want. quick guide at the bottom of [this page](https://trumpexcel.com/concatenate-excel-ranges/)

Answer (score 0):

`TEXTJOIN()` will let you make a delimited list from a range of cells

```
="INSERT INTO languages(en) VALUES ('" & TEXTJOIN("'), ('",TRUE,B1:B4) & "');"
```